# Stash notifier plugin for jenkins generates the wrong jenkins URL

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, bitbucket-server

I am using the Stash Notifier plugin on jenkins to notify Stash of sucessful builds. When you click on the link for the build (Green tick link) in Stash, it pops up a dialog with a link back to jenkins. The URL it uses to link back to jenkins is wrong. I can't see anywhere to configure it.

Does anyone know where this link can be configured to use the right URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log into jenkins as Admin

- Select Jenkins (top left of screen)
- From the drop down select 'Manage Jenkins'
- Select 'Configure System'
- About half way down the page there is a menu Jenkins Location, and under that there is an item 'Jenkins URL'
- Add the correct URL
- Save and exit